# Defines with environment variables as value in bcc32 compiler

Tags: c++builder

I would like to know how I can get a define with an environment variable as value in bcc32 compiler.

The environment variable is `%SVN_REVISION%`, so I tried this:

```
bcc32.exe -DSVN_REV=%SVN_REVISION%
```

....  but it returns a syntax error.

Comment: What is the reported syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Since `define` is handled by the [preprocessor](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) at compile time, it cannot know the value of any environment variable on the machine the compiled byte code will later be run on, thus it will throw a syntax error.

Comment: I think what JohnnPaul is trying to do is get the command-line processor to first interpret `%SVN_REVISION%` and pass its concrete value to `-D` when invoking bcc32.exe, ie `-DSVN_REV=12345`, as `-D` values are accessible to the preprocessor during compiling.

Comment: Ah. Completely different story then. My mistake.